# Dividing a number into 12 integers equally

Tags: algorithm

I want to divide an integer N, which is a number of work days to 12 months as equally as possible so if I take a any period of 2,3,4,5,6 months the work days are still divided as equally as possible in that period. Lecturer said that I have to use some kind of rounding up algorithm, however I can't think of anything. Any algorithm suggestions or links would help a lot.

Comment: Something is missing in your requirements: giving 1 day per month for N months seems to fit, but probably should not.

Comment: What have you tried ?  What have you got so far ?  I judge by your use of the word 'lecturer' that you are in tertiary education.  Surely someone as smart as you has been able to start solving this problem already and didn't just think for about 30sec and then ask for help.

Comment: If you have to divide 13 into 12 'as equal as possible chunks', you get 11 chunks with 1 and one chunk with 2; 14 gives 10 and 2; 15 gives 9 and 3 (12 gives 12 and 0), etc.  For arbitrary N, you get N ÷ 12 (integer division) days for 12 - (N % 12) units, and (N ÷ 12) + 1 for (N % 12) units, where % is the modulo operator.

Comment: Try thinking of specific cases with different values of N.  See what you would come up with for each case, and then look for a pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You need to choose a number `k` so that some of the months have `k` work-days put in them, and the others have `k+1`. That's as close as you can get to an equal division without splitting work-days. The number of months with `k+1` in them is equal to N modulo 12 (`N % 12` in many programming languages).

Answer (score 1):

You start with how many days per months you need to work AT LEAST:

```
days = floor(N / 12)
```

(where floor(...) means to round down.)

And then you have some remainder:

```
remainder = N % 12
```

(where % means modulo)

Notice that remainder is definitely less than 12, because we used modulo

So spread these remainder days across the 12 months however you like.

(**Note** this approach generalizes to any number of months, just substitute in the # of months wherever we used 12 above)